# Problem put axios update user Strapi and NuxtJS

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, strapi

I have a problem with the right in **strapi**.

I create user with the role Authenticated and try modified the data with axios.

But it is impossible has modified because return forbidden. I look if the user has right, **Update** is check in role authenticated.

If i check update in role public, my modification with axios is ok. Why ? I don't undestand the problem.

My code for send

````
       .put(
         `https://localhost:4000/users/${this.data.id}`,
         {
           headers: {
             Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
           },
           Nom: 'JEAN'
         }
       )
       .then((res) => {
         // Handle success.
         console.log(res)
       })
       .catch((error) => {
         // Handle error.
         console.error('An error occurred:', error)
       })```

Thank you
````

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the axios request has the right format.

According to this documentation - https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosconfig

This probably should look like this:

```
axios({
  method: 'put',
  url: `https://localhost:4000/users/${this.data.id}`,
  data: {
    username: 'JEAN'
  },
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
  }
});
```